# SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi while creating a onclick function with dynamic input paramenters i am getting the above error. Any help is appreciated:

```
var id= data.persons[i].person_Id ;
                $("#cntxtMenuSelect").append("<a href='#' onClick='someFunc(\'" + id + "\')'>"+id+"</a><br>");
```

Comment: Don't inline javascript when you use jQuery ! Do you really want to spend your time counting the quotes ?

Comment: Conflicting quoting here: `onClick='someFunc(\'" ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create proper elements with proper event handlers

```
var anchor = $('<a />', {
    href : '#',
    on   : {
        click : function() {
             someFunc(data.persons[i].person_Id);
        }
    },
    text : data.persons[i].person_Id
}),
    br = $('<br />');

$("#cntxtMenuSelect").append(anchor, br);
```

Comment: TIL definiting attributes in jQuery is a lot easier than I do it currently. +1 for learning!

Comment: @SterlingArcher - it's actually really easy, but you don't see it very often, people tend to create elements and then chain on `text()`, `attr()`, `on()` and what not. jQuery's way of creating elements will accept any jQuery method directly in the following object.

Comment: Exactly, I would chain attributes etc, and had no idea it took a simple object param. Brilliant

Comment: HI sorry for the delay. Thanks a million for your help. It resolved the initial issue. But i am faced with a different issue now. I did as you asked and it worked but on clicking any link i am always getting the last value of the array even though the text field is showing the correct value

Comment: That probably has to do with the value of `i` in your code, the loop completes and `i` will be the last value it was set to when the click happens later